# Identifying video segments that, when looped, appear continuous

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I want to be able to take a video and extract segments that, when looped, appear continuous for the purposes of creating animated GIFs en masse.

Step one would obviously be extracting each frame of the video as an image.  My current idea is to take the difference of every frame and it's following N frames and look for a very small difference.  That is to say, simply search for segments where the last frame closely resembles the first frame.

Does this seem like a viable way to accomplish this task?  If not, what would be a better way?  If so, how would I accomplish taking the difference of images?

Comment: Just found this to work from, going to do some reading: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2015/02/01/extracting-perfectly-looping-gifs-from-videos-with-python-and-moviepy/